# Spring Boot @ManyToMany not showing in JSON

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am trying to get all info from `User` entity which include shoes that user have from `Shoes` entity. When I try to call `findAll()`, it gets only the information from one table but ignores the joined table. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

```
    //Shoes
    @Entity
    public class Shoes implements Serializable {
        private Integer shoesId;
        private Integer shoesCode;
        private String shoesColor;
        private String shoesSeason;
        private String shoesType;
        private String shoesPicture;
        private String shoesShortDescription;
        private String shoesFullDescription;
        private String shoesPrice;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userShoes")
        private Set<User> userSet;
//getters and setters


//User
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Integer userId;
    private String userLogin;
    private String userPassword;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userBirthDay;
    private String userFacebookId;
    private String userGoogleId;
    private String userAvatar;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Shoes.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_shoes",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "shoes_id")})
    private Set<Shoes> userShoes;

//getters and setters
```

I'm using JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ShoesRepository extends JpaRepository<Shoes, Serializable> {

    List<Shoes> findShoesByShoesColorAndShoesSeason(String shoesColor, String shoesSeason);
}
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Serializable> {

}
```

The Controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/items")
public class ShoesController {

    private ShoesService shoesService;

    @Autowired
    public ShoesController(ShoesService shoesService) {
        this.shoesService = shoesService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/shoes/test")
    public String hello(){
        return "HelloWorld";
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "shoes")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Shoes>> getAll(){
        List<Shoes> allshoes = new ArrayList<>();
                shoesService.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(allshoes::add);
        if (allshoes.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allshoes, HttpStatus.OK);
    } }

@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/users")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "user")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll(){
        List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
                userService.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(allUsers::add);
        if (allUsers.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allUsers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } }
```

I'm using Postman to test:
http://localhost:8080/v1/users/user
get a JSON:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "userLogin": "fsdfsdf",
        "userPassword": "sdfsdfsdf",
        "userFirstName": "fsdfds",
        "userLastName": "fsdfsd",
        "userEmail": "dfsf",
        "userBirthDay": "sdfsdfs",
        "userFacebookId": "sdfdsfsd",
        "userGoogleId": "fsdfsd",
        "userAvatar": "sdsdf"
    }
]
```

But with no shoes property.

http://localhost:8080/v1/items/shoes

```
[
    {
        "shoesId": 1,
        "shoesCode": 23432234,
        "shoesColor": "dsfsdf",
        "shoesSeason": "fsdfs",
        "shoesType": "fsdsdf",
        "shoesPicture": "sdfsdf",
        "shoesShortDescription": "dfsdfsd",
        "shoesFullDescription": "sdfsdf",
        "shoesPrice": "sdfsd"
    }
]
```

But with no user property.

Comment: Do you have public getter defined on userShoes? if not you should add it or force jackson to use field (eg. by `@JsonProperty` or changing AutoDetect strategy through `@JsonAutoDetect`)

Comment: And as a side note: `userService.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(allUsers::add)` is not very efficient as it could potentially force `ArrayList` to resize mutliple times and anyway why you're not just returning the userService.findAll()?

Comment: Have alook at: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: do you have a associations between shows and users in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found resolusion in main class. 
I really don't know why someone add annotations:

```
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan({"com.ua.demoClothes"})
@EntityScan("com.ua.demoClothes.entity")
@JsonAutoDetect
```

but when it was removed it started workind propertly. Just with

`@SpringBootApplication`

in main class

and

```
@JsonBackReference
@JsonManagedReference
```

in entities class